# Make list with strings

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to make a list from other list:

```
   list1={A,B,C,S}; list2=Table[i,{i,1,end}];
```

Then my list three will be `i->j`where i are elements of list2 and j the elements of list 1 (repeated until `end`  )

Comment: `Thread[list2 -> list1]`?

Comment: Try do show your own code effort and further explain where the variable "end"  implies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the lists can be of unequal [`Length`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html), `Length[list1] >= Length[list2]`, and `list2` cycles as required

```
list1 = {"A", "B", "C", "S"};

list2 = Range[3];

Thread[list1 -> PadRight[list2, Length[list1], list2]]

(* {"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3, "S" -> 1} *)
```